# What is this the correct name for this skinny-pergola type structure?

Tags: roses, support, trellis

We're looking to grow roses onto something like the structure pictured below. We'd like to look at photos of various forms, however I don't know what to search for. Pergola and trellis give very limited results.

Is there an architectural term for this mini pergola ?

[image]

Edit: This came up using [Lorel C.'s suggestion](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35911/what-is-this-the-correct-name-for-this-skinny-pergola-type-structure/35912#35912) that it might be called an "arbor." This is what I'm looking for, only it would be much longer, running the entire length of a patio. There MUST be a special name for this thing.

[image]

Comment: You got it, its a pergola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the UK, I'd describe this as a 'single or single row wooden pergola', but have seen them sometimes called an arch. Here's an example of a single pergola, shown with a trellis infill
https://www.jacksons-fencing.co.uk/fencing/secret-garden-collection/pergolas-single/secret-garden-collection-pergolas-single.aspx

Answer (score 3):

How about an "arbor"? It looks like a trellis is usually a smaller closed flat structure (i.e. you don't look through it), and a pergola is a more substantial "3-d" thing.

Answer (score 3):

Google image search suggests [landscaping trellis](https://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en-NZ&q=landscaping%20trellis&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ1bC_l4jXAhUKHZQKHYYXAFgQvQ4IJygE).

Though I built one at our last house and I called it a pergola.